# C# Are we able to control which line to write in richtextbox?

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I want to copy the text I type in a textbox to a richtextbox. It will automatically appear in richtextbox while I type in the textbox. I do something like below:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = textBox1.Text;
        richTextBox1.Font = new Font("Comic Sans MS", 14);
    }
```

But when we use richtextbox, the text will always begin to appear on the first line on top left side. Let say I want the textbox's text to appear in the 3rd line of the richtextbox. How do we do it?

Comment: You can append Line breaks as well to start from 3rd line

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        richTextBox1.Text = "\r\n\r\n"+"          "+ textBox1.Text; // Appended Spaces
        richTextBox1.Font = new Font("Comic Sans MS", 14);
    }
```

This trick will workout!

For Center Alignment

```
richTextBox1.SelectAll();
richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
```

Comment: Thanks #Fayed Ali Khan.. Can we not start in the left side. Let say I wan the text to start in the middle of 3rd line. How?

Comment: @Coolguy dear , There are two things to center align text or to just start 3rd line text from center ?

Comment: @Coolguy For Center Alignment i have updated the code, please check and for Just Starting the 3rd line text in the center , you can append some white space

Comment: Thanks @ Fayeq Ali Khan for the center allignment comment. But what if I want it to appear not that center, let say.. 10 space from the left. How?

Answer (score 0):

You may try it to write in **3rd** line

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = "\r\n" + "\r\n" +textBox1.Text;
        richTextBox1.Font = new Font("Comic Sans MS", 14);
    }
```

For alignment

```
richTextBox1.SelectAll();
richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
```

To add Space from left

```
richTextBox1.Text += new String(' ', n);
```

n is the number of space you want to add.

Comment: Thanks @Atish Dipongkor.. Can we not start in the left side. Let say I wan the text to start in the middle of 3rd line. How?

Comment: Thanks @Atish Dipongkor for the center allignment comment. But what if I want it to appear not that center, let say.. 10 space from the left. How?

Comment: Append 10 space to it first

Comment: How do we append # Atish Dipongkor?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35493/discussion-between-atish-dipongkor-and-coolguy)

Comment: Thanks @Atish Dipongkor. Then let say I want the first word in line 3 to appear in font 16 and the second word to appear in font 20. How do we do it? The font 14 I use above applies to all text.

Comment: Select and then set font

Comment: How do we select and set font?

Comment: Search in google. http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=146

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228088/c-sharp-richtextbox-select-specified-text