# C# - Find text inside a certain string in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#

Lets say a rich text box has this inside:

```
This is a rich text box with a hidden meaning.
```

How would I find all text between `a` and `a`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# RichTextBox Select specified Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228088/c-sharp-richtextbox-select-specified-text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use RegEx:

```
Regex.Match("This is a rich text box with a hidden meaning.", @"a([^a]*)a").Groups[1].Value
```